# Running appium in saucelabs cloud devices changing public ip for country specific applications testing

Tags: java, appium, saucelabs

im running our automated tests successfully in saucelabs android devices (we are yet to try our iOS device tests), but our tests are failing because our application only works if the ip address of the device that made the request (in the background api) is from our country, Argentina, because the service we provide only works in this country, but, SauceLabs devices are located in europe.

Currently i tried to change the device location with appium, to the gps coordinates from argentina, but our application don't care about it, only the public ip address of the request.

So the question is if there is any way that i can point the public ip of the device to an argentinian one, so that the tests run successfully. Maybe a appium capability of some sort, (but i didn't see any like that) or some souceLabs specific feature to do that maybe.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you use a VPN on the device to route the traffic thru Argentina?

Answer (score 1):

There's no Appium or Sauce capability to achieve this.  In fact, since it sounds like the Background API is the component responsible for checking the IP address, I'm not sure it even could be addressed automatically; you can't change an IP address' geo-location.

What you could do is make traffic appear to originate from another address using
[Sauce Connect](https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Sauce+Connect+Proxy).  By starting that in Argentina and using it in your tests, your traffic will appear to originate from the location you run the client.

To use Sauce Connect with Real Devices, you'll need to making use of the new Real Device platform (eg, not the old TestObject interface).  You can read more about Sauce with Real Devices here: https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Sauce+Connect+Proxy+Setup+for+Real+Device+Cloud